# Create association on non-primary key fields with Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, primary-key, entity-framework-4.1

We are using EF 4.1 and the fluent API to get data from a legacy database (that we are not permitted to change). We are having a problem creating a relationship between two tables where the related columns are *not* primary and foreign keys.

With the classes below, how would we configure the one-to-many relationship between `Report` and `RunStat` such that `Report.RunStats` would return all of the `RunStat` entities where the `ReportCode` fields are equal?

```
public class Report
{
    [Key]
    public int ReportKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ReportCode { get; set; } // Can we associate on this field?
    public virtual ICollection<RunStat> RunStats { get; set; }
}

public class RunStat
{
    [Key]
    public int RunStatKey { get; set; }
    public int ReportCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime RunDate { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I want to use the Fluent API to configure EF such that it considers `Report.ReportCode` to be the foreign key and `RunStat.ReportCode` to be the primary key.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible. Relations in EF follows exactly same rules as in the database. It means that principal table must have unique identifier which is referenced by dependent table. In case of database the identifier can be either primary key or unique column(s) of principal table. Otherwise it is not valid relation.

Entity framework doesn't support unique keys. If you want to have one-to-many relation between `Report` and `RunStat` your dependent table (`RunStat`) must contains column with value of `Report.ReportKey`. There is no other way to make it automatic - otherwise you must simply make it custom property and fill it from entity framework manually when you need it.

Comment: Vote to add this as a new feature in Entity Framework http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Answer (score 3):

This capability is now possible in **EF Core 1.0** (EF7) as indicated in the reference provided by [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184574/brian) on Jul 16, 2014 to a [feature request posted to Microsoft's UserVoice forum](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support).

So that this valuable information is not lost should this information disappear at the referenced page, here is the text of the feature request:

> **Unique Constraint (i.e. Candidate Key) Support**
>   *<sub>(posted by Kati Iceva on Sep 10, 2010)</sub>*
>
> SQL Server and other databases support Unique Constraints on tables.
>   Foreign key constraints are generally based on unique constraints on
>   the principal side, with the Primary Key being only a special case of
>   a unique constraint. The Entity Framework currently only supports
>   basing referential constraints on primary keys and does not have a
>   notion of a unique constraint. The idea is to have:
>
> - Support for specifying a unique constraint on an Entity
> - Support for specifying a foreign key associations that on the principal end specify columns(s) that comprise a unique constraint but
>     are not the primary key.

And Microsoft's announcement of the implementation of this capability in EF Core 1.0:

> **Completed**
>   *<sub>(posted by Diego Vega (Program Manager, Microsoft Entity Framework) on Aug 9, 2016)</sub>*
>
> Closing as support for this feature was added in EF Core 1.0 and we
>   don’t have plans to add it in the EF6 codebase. Also, please create
>   new ideas for specific improvements to the feature.

Comment: You can now specify a [principal key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#principal-key)