# EF5 Navigation/Association Property with non-Primary Foreign Key

Tags: entity-framework-5

This is the same exact question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9217448/entity-framework-foreign-keys-to-non-primary-key-fields), but instead for EF5.

Is it possible now?

We have a Users table that has an int PK, but in our other tables that have columns like InsertBy/UpdateBy, the desire is to use value of the LANID varchar column from the Users table, rather than the UserID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is still not possible. FK must target PK in the principal table because EF still doesn't support unique keys (prerequisite for using non-PK columns).

Comment: boo EF whyyy :( -- no bother, we changed the model which simplified the relationship