# Entity Framework 6: Relationship without using Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let's say I have a data model that looks like so:

```
dbo.Application
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   int ClientAlternateId { get; set; }
   ...

   public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

dbo.Client
{
   int Id { get; set; }
   int AlternateId { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Where the primary key on both tables is the `Id` column.  the `Application` type is associated to the `Client` table via its `AlternateId` column (which is not a key).  The data in this column is always unique.

Is there a way to get entity framework to map this?  I don't believe I'll be able to use:

```
    HasRequired(t => t.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.ClientAlternateId);
```

since that field is not the primary key.

Comment: No. Associations always require primary keys. EF doesn't support associations with unique indexes (yet).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create association on non-primary key fields with Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019052/create-association-on-non-primary-key-fields-with-entity-framework-4-1-fluent-ap)

Comment: Vote to add this as a new feature in Entity Framework http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Answer (score -1):

When configuring the relationship in your AppDbContext you need to add `.HasPrincipalKey()`
, this article might help
https://gavilan.blog/2019/04/14/entity-framework-core-foreign-key-linked-with-a-non-primary-key/